# displaying last SQL database record on the top row in a html table in PHP

Tags: php

Hi below code prints results from first saved to last saved. Is there a way to get last saved on the top row once the data is displayed? (All records in the reverse order.) thanks.

```
while ($recz = mysql_fetch_array($runz))
{

    echo "<tr class='taB'>";
    echo "<td>".$recz["chkNum"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$recz["InvoNum"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$recz["InvoVal"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$recz["InvoDate"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$recz["type"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='ta'>".$recz["statu"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You want *ONLY* the last row on top, or you want the records in reverse order?

Comment: Yes GarethL all records in reverse order.

Comment: In that case, Travesty3's answer below is perfect; you need to add `ORDER BY ... DESC` to your sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change your query. Use [`ORDER BY ...  DESC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html), where the `...` is the column name that determines the order of the results.

In your HTML output, it looks like you have a column named `InvoDate`. Perhaps that's the column you need. If so, your query would end with `ORDER BY InvoDate DESC`.